# How to erase a plus sign for ACL permission?

Tags: permissions

I use a hosting server of FreeBSD 10.3, where I don't have the authority to be the super user, and use apache2 on it for web pages of our company.
The previous administrator of the web pages appeared to set ACL permission to a directory but I want to remove it. Let's say the directory as foobar.

Now the result of 'ls -al foobar' is as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x+   2 myuser  another_user   512 Nov 20  2013 foobar
```

And the permission is as follows:

```
[myuser@hosting_server]$ getfacl foobar
# file: foobar/
# owner: myuser
# group: another_user
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Here I want to remove the ACL permission and the plus sign at the last of permission list. So, I did

```
setfacl -b foobar
```

It eliminated the special permission governed by ACL but didn't erase the plus sign.

My question is how can I erase the plus sign in the permission list shown by 'ls -al foobar'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "setfacl -bn".  Otherwise it will leave the "mask" entry.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the inode cache.

```
\# sync; echo 2 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```